# Signature for this request is not valid - BINANCE

Tags: node.js, binance

I did exactly what I asked in the api documentation, and it didn't work, does anyone know what's wrong

```
  var axios = require('axios');
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const apiSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  const query_string = `timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', apiSecret)
    .update(query_string)
    .digest('hex')

  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order?symbol=BTCUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&quantity=1&price=61000.97&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}&signature=${signature}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.msg);
    });
```

Comment: From https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security, `timestamp` needs to be part of the signed query params. If you change it after signing, the signature won't be valid.

Comment: Additionally, the content type of the request is probably going to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`.

Comment: Return me an HTML page

Comment: Um, can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: {code: -1021, msg: 'Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time.'}

Comment: Okay, so the signature is now (presumably) valid, you need to ensure that your local clock is spot on (or at least not in the future).